# ¿Como realizar un update con mongoose y nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, sailsjs, mongodb

tengo el siguiente código para una actualización, el problema es que no se si se puedan actualizar mas de un campo y si es así, como seria?

```
     Boleta.update({serie: serie}, {firma: parametros}, function (err, firma){
         if (err) {
             return res.status(500).send({
                success: false,
                message: "Internal Server Error. Update fenomenos"
            });
         };

         if (firma == '') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Fenomenos Not Found.'
           });
         };

         return res.json({
           success: true,
           message: 'Firma de fenomenos exitosa.',
           firma: firma[0].firma
        });
   });
```

Me gustaría actualizar la serie pero no se si lo que estoy haciendo mal o porque no me funciona...

```
Boleta.update({serie: serie}, {$set:{firma: parametros,serie:serie+"F"}, function (err, firma){...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> no se si se puedan actualizar mas de un campo

Sí es posible, de hecho, es un comportamiento normal.

> si es así, ¿cómo seria?

En mongoose hay dos formas de actualizar:

- Mediante el modelo
- Mediante una instancia del modelo

---

**Actualizar mediante el modelo**

Ésta forma es la que estás utilizando tú. La función [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) de [`Mongoose#Model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model), recibe como dos primeros parámetros lo siguiente:

- Objeto de condiciones. Estos valores sirven para saber qué documento va a ser actualizado.
- Objeto de nuevos valores. Est objeto **contiene los nuevos valores** a guardar.

> Es recomendable utilizar promesas en lugar de callbacks con Mongoose

Para actualizar un documento, basta con:

```
Boleta.update(
  {serie: serie},
  {firma: parametros}
).then((rawResponse) => {

})
.catch((err) => {
  // manejar error
});
```

El código anterior actualiza el campo `firma` de la boleta con `serie` "X". Ten en cuenta que, `parametros` debe ser exactamente el mismo tipo de dato que has definido en el modelo de `Boleta`.

**Nota:** la función `update` no devuelve el documento actualizado. Devuelve la respuesta plana de MongoDB. Esta respuesta contiene datos como *campos afectados*, etc.

**Actualizar mediante instancia**

Este método es mucho más sencillo, además de útil cuando quieres devolver el documento afectado. Lo que se hace aquí es encontrar el documento y agregarle mediante propiedades los nuevos valores.

```
Boleta.findOne({
  serie: req.params.id
})
.then((boleta) => {
  boleta.firma = req.params.firma;
  boleta
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.jsonp({ boleta }); // enviamos la boleta de vuelta
    });
});
```

---

> no se si lo que estoy haciendo mal o por qué no me funciona

Cuando una actualización no se produce en Mongoose es principalmente porque **ha ocurrido un error de validación**. Generalmente ocurre cuando establecemos valores no válidos para esa propiedad, por ejemplo, guardar un text en un campo `Number`. Cuando ocurren éstos casos, Mongoose lanza un `MongooseError`, el cual tiene toda la información del error que ha sucedido. Puedes capturar éste error en un catch y manejarlo.

```
try {
  // actualizar documento
} catch(e) {
  let errors = e.errors;
  res.jsonp({
    errors,
    success: false
  });
}
```

---

**Consejo:** antes de proceder a actualizar, valida la información entrante, de tal modo que evites en lo posibe errores en tiempo de ejecución y así el usuario podrá saber qué errores en la validación han ocurrido.

Comment: Gracias @guzgarcia por el consejo, si lo tengo ya implementado y verifiqué que la información sea correcta, el problema era que no me actualizaba, pero ya está...