# Optimizar dos llamadas a la base de datos con Moongose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, moongose

Tengo una función que sirve para editar un producto. De este se puede editar campos como nombre, categoría, y especialmente **precioCosto** y **precioVenta**. Si se edita alguno de estos dos campos, debe ir a otra función que guarda los precios anteriores en un histórico de precios. Para realizar esto, trate de hacerlo de esta forma:

```js
let editProduct = (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let body = _.pick(req.body, ['codigo', 'descripcion', 'nombre', 'precioCosto', 'precioVenta', 'categoria', 'marca']);
  Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query', useFindAndModify: false }, (err, productoUpdate) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        ok: false,
        error: 'Error interno'
      });
    }
    if (!productoUpdate) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        error: {
          message: 'Producto no encontrado'
        }
      });
    }
    if(body.precioCosto != productoEncontrado.precioCosto || body.precioVenta != productoEncontrado.precioVenta) {
      closePriceHistory(productoUpdate);
      addPriceHistory(productoUpdate);
    }
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      producto: productoUpdate._id
    });
  });
}
```

El problema de este código, es que nunca entraba a:

```js
if(
  productoUpdate.precioCosto != productoEncontrado.precioCosto ||
  productoUpdate.precioVenta != productoEncontrado.precioVenta
) { ... }
```

porque el producto se editaba y luego miraba esas propiedades. Lo solucioné de esta manera:

```js
let editProduct = (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let body = _.pick(req.body, ['codigo', 'descripcion', 'nombre', 'precioCosto', 'precioVenta', 'categoria', 'marca']);
  Producto.findById(id, '_id nombre precioCosto precioVenta').exec((err, productoEncontrado) => {
    if (err){
      res.status(500).json({
        ok: false,
        error: 'Error interno'
      });
    }
    if(!productoEncontrado) {
      res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        error: 'Producto no encontrado'
      });
    }
    Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query', useFindAndModify: false }, (err, productoUpdate) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          ok: false,
          error: 'Error interno'
        });
      }
      if (!productoUpdate) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          ok: false,
          error: {
            message: 'Producto no encontrado'
          }
        });
      }
      if (productoUpdate.precioCosto != productoEncontrado.precioCosto || productoUpdate.precioVenta != productoEncontrado.precioVenta) {
        closePriceHistory(productoUpdate);
        addPriceHistory(productoUpdate);
      }
      res.json({
        ok: true,
        producto: productoUpdate._id
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Funcionar, funciona. Pero ¿hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo? Para no realizar dos *queries* a Mongo.
Gracias.

Comment: Viendo tu caso de uso diría que no. Si tienes un sistema monolítico podrías implementar una caché local y consultar esos valores en la caché. Haz esto solo cuando estés seguro de que lanzar esas dos queries es un problema.

Comment: Ok entonces para aclarar, me recomendas que lo deje de esta manera?

Comment: Yo lo probaría conforme lo tienes. Si te preocupa el rendimiento ante situaciones de estrés lo habitual es hacer pruebas de carga y ver cuando y dónde empiezas a tener cuellos de botella. Por cierto, no muestras lo que hacen las funciones que actualizan los históricos, pero probablemente hagan más operaciones contra BBDD... Mi consejo es que empieces a optimizar esos procesos, única y exclusivamente cuando sea necesario, ya que, quizás hacer lo que planteas de manera escalable implique no solo una simple refactorización de código. (Colas de mensajería, cachés, microservicios, ...)

Comment: Quizás una mejora de código que se puede apreciar es que en el segundo ejemplo, `findByIdAndUpdate` no es necesario, puede usar lo que comentan en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47491/6095

Comment: Buenisimo, muchas gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo